# Lagrange's interpolation to solve for 0 of y(x)

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I have the data composing of 7 elements

x is from 0 → 3 incrementing by 0.5
y is from 1.8241 → -1.5427

I am supposed to use Lagrange's interpolation of three nearest neighbor data points.

I am supposed to write the code to do so in python but am struggling with setting up the equation.

I know l[0] = (x-x1/(x[0]-x[1])(x[0]-x[2])

But given the question that doesn't seem to be what I need and if so, using the 3 nearest neighbor data points do I still start at l[0].

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For the sample at zero, just assume that $x[-1] = 0$. Likewise for the sample locations past $3$. You can also find examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Examples).